# Android AsyncTask accessing and updating VideoView

Tags: android, view, android-videoview

I need to monitor the buffer percentage of VideoView continuously while a video is playing on the foreground. I created a AsyncTask class and passed the VideoView on to that class. However, when I try to access the buffer percentage it always return 0. I initialized and started video playback on the onCreate method of my Main activity. my code:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static MediaController mc;
static VideoView vw;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mc = new MediaController(this);

    vw = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    vw.setVideoPath("http://173.45.164.105:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8");
    vw.requestFocus();
    vw.start();

    // Execute async task for stream error
    ConnCheck cc = new ConnCheck();
    cc.execute();

    Log.i("REACHED MAIN", "Started Playing");
}
```

}

```
    class ConnCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while (MainActivity.vw.isPlaying() == true) {

        Log.i("HEY", "DOING STUFF");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you using  "
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent) " in your code?

Comment: My problem is that vw.isPlaying is not evaluating to true because it never prints out my debug statement to the logcat even though the video is playing and getBufferPercentage() call always returns 0.

Comment: I still don't get why isPlaying is not evaluating to true while the video is playing.

Comment: Are you able to find out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the video in `OnCreate()` method, but at that instant it has not started playing and you execute your asynctask just after starting the video. So when the `doInBackground()` is exceuted, `MainActivity.vw.isPlaying()` returns **false** and hence the vm never enters the loop you have created. I hope you understand the difference between started and playing.
And the solution of your problem is to implement this method

```
public abstract void onBufferingUpdate (MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
```

Comment: So how do I detect that the video is playing?

Comment: `MainActivity.vw.isPlaying()` will return true when the video has started playing. I think you should refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)